# Is the result of "generalization" algorithm the same every time using it in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox

I have a database with roads, and i update it oftenly. For another department we give them the same database but generalized so they can fit the forest to the roads.

I wanted to know if you use generalize on the same database several times, do you get the same results regarding lines that haven't change since?

I mean, do the unchanged roads have still the same geometry and vertex number so they still fits with the forest from the previous work?

Comment: I wouldn't trust too much on that. Result can well be identical with the same ArcGIS version and platform but I would not be surprised in seeing some differences between Linux/Windows, 32/64 bit and different ArcGIS versions. Simplify once, store the results in some safe place and reuse the same geometries until an edit in the main data triggers them outdated.

Comment: there are different algorithms to generalise in ArcGIS, which one are you using ?

Comment: I'm using just Generalize (Editing) with a tolerance 1.5m

Comment: I think this is one where you should test to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the same machine and same ArcGIS version and using shape files, then you get the same results.

But if you are on a geodatabase you must consider the geodatabase resolution because you can get minor changes while moving feature class from one to one other and executing generalized at the new geodatabase on the already imported feature class.